# Как пишется приставка "по" с наречиями?

Tags: орфография, наречия, морфемика, слитно-дефис, приставка

В каких случаях приставка "по" с наречиями пишется слитно, а в каких — через дефис?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Приставка "по" с наречиями пишется через дефис только, если наречие заканчивается на суффиксы "-ому", "-ему", "-и".
Примеры: *по-нов**ому**, по-прежн**ему**, по-русск**и***.
В остальных случаях "по" пишется слитно.
Примеры: *поярче, побольше*.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, расскажу ещё о некоторых случаях.

Если наречие с приставкой *по* оканчивается на -ОМУ- (ЕМУ), -СКИ-, -КИ-, -ЬИ-, то такое наречие пишется через дефис. Примеры: по-волчьи, по-немецки, по-своему, по-свойски, по-братски.

И ещё об одном случае. Если есть приставка ПО, а наречие оканчивается на У, то такое наречие пишется слитно. Например: потихоньку.

Comment: не путать с -ому/-ему

Answer (score 1):

"По" с наречиями пишется через дефис, если это наречие заканчивается суффиксами -ому и -ему. А в остальных случаях "по" пишется слитно.

Comment: "...если это наречие заканчивается суффиксами -ому и -ему..." и "и".